# Can I use XPath to get the content of a processing instruction in XML?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a very simple XML snippet that is stored in a file that needs to be updated.
Unfortunately it is a processing instruction that I need to have updated.

Can I use XPath to get the content of the processing instruction, or at least part of it?

For example:

```
<Include>
   <?define Version="2.0"?>
</Include>
```

I need to get the value of "Version".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath expression:

```
substring-before(
   substring-after(
      /Include/processing-instruction('define'),
      'Version="'
   ),
   '"'
)
```

Evaluate to the string: `'2.0'`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get '2.0'. You can get 'Version="2.0"' in a single value, then manually extract the '2.0' out of it. It is part of xml spec. If you wish to get 2.0, make sure that you use `<define Version='2.0/>` (use element instead of processing instruction).

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [here](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N6145.html#d8657e109),

> The "attributes" in processing
>   instructions aren't actually
>   attributes -- they just look like
>   them. Noramally people refer to these
>   kinds of "attributes" as
>   "pseudo-attributes" to emphasise that
>   fact. As far as the XPath data model
>   is concerned, the only information you
>   can get about a processing instruction
>   is its target, its value and its
>   location in the node tree.

So you can get to the node itself with

```
/Include/processing-instruction('define')
```

but all that gets you is a node with a `Value` of `Version="2.0"` (as a string), which you must then parse yourself.