# XPath for value within an XML processing instruction (PI)?

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm attempting to retrieve a specific value from an XML file for use in a wix MSBUILD. (I want the version to be in the output filename, surprisingly not an easy task!)
If there is a better non XPath solution, I'm all ears.

I would like to extract the `9.11`, but cannot seem to trim down the results of my query. The query returns the ALL of the elements.

My .wxi file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Include>
    <?define ProductName = "ACME Software" ?>
    <?define ProductManufacturer = "ACME Inc." ?>
    <?define ProductVersion="9.99" ?>
    <?define Version="9.11" ?>
</Include>
```

My query

`//*[processing-instruction()[contains(.,'Version')]]`

My result

```
<Include>
    <?define ProductName = "ACME Software" ?>
    <?define ProductManufacturer = "ACME Inc." ?>
    <?define ProductVersion="9.99" ?>
    <?define Version="9.11" ?>
</Include>
```

How do I extract just the one value from the single `<?define` ?

I've been using [CodeBeautify](https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester) for testing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use XPath to get the content of a processing instruction in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547579/can-i-use-xpath-to-get-the-content-of-a-processing-instruction-in-xml)

Comment: I tried the solution there but it did not return anything from my xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt,

```
//*[processing-instruction()[contains(.,'Version')]]
```

selects all elements with processing instruction children that contain a `"Version"` substring.  Thus, your observed result that the selection is the `Include` element since it has such a child processing instruction.

Instead, this XPath,

```
substring-before(
  substring-after(/Include/processing-instruction('define')[contains(.,"Version=")],
                  'Version="'), 
  '"')
```

will perform substring manipulation on the string value of the `define` processing instruction whose string value contains a `'Version="'` substring and evaluate to

```
9.99
```

as requested.

**Credit:** [Can I use XPath to get the content of a processing instruction in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5547579/290085)